# Formula to calculate body fat percentage

Tags: java, android

```
private void calculateBodyFatPercentage() {
    double weight = Double.parseDouble(weightBF.getText().toString());
    double height = Double.parseDouble(heightBF.getText().toString());
    double waistCircumference = Double.parseDouble(waistBF.getText().toString());
    String spinnerGenderBF = spngender.getSelectedItem().toString();

    double bodyFatPercentage = (double)calculateBodyFatPercentage(weight, height, waistCircumference, spinnerGenderBF);
    resultBF.setText("Estimated Body Fat Percentage: " + bodyFatPercentage + "%");
}

private double calculateBodyFatPercentage(double weight, double height, double waistCircumference, String gender) {
    // Paste the body fat percentage calculation logic from the previous code here
    double factorA, factorB;

    if (gender.equals("Male")) {
        factorA = 86.010;
        factorB = 70.041;
    } else{
        factorA = 163.205;
        factorB = 97.684;
    }

    double bodyDensity = factorA - (factorB * Math.log10(waistCircumference - height));
    double bodyFatPercentage = (495 / bodyDensity) - 450;

    return bodyFatPercentage;
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

The result based on the code I provide.

I do not understand why I can get NaN% value. How to fix it?

Comment: Please check out [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/)  and [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). The links won't solve your direct problem, but they will give you steps that you can follow that should help you solve it yourself, or even if that is not successful, then at least help you to better isolate your problem so that your question can be more focused and easier to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some calculation mistake,

```
your waistCircumference = 60
your height = 170
```

when you do

```
Math.log10(waistCircumference - height)
```

it will not give the expected answer since we cannot have negative numbers inside log10

I hope it answers your query!
Happy coding!

Comment: I try to adjust formula by doing Math.log10(height - waistCircumference) and it give negative value instead of NaN. But, it is okay as I already plan to make another calculator. Thanks for the comment

Comment: Hi, Its good that you plan  to make another calculator, If you find this answer useful then you can mark it as a accepted answer. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in Math.log10, the log function doesn't take negative values, so it returns nan as waistCircumference - height < 0. If you could attach the formula you used, maybe i recommend you a solution.

Comment: I get the formula from chatGPT as I just want to train my coding skill. But, it is okay as I already plan to make another calculator. Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0):

The value NaN is used to represent a value that is an error. This is represented when exponent field is all ones with a zero sign bit or a mantissa that it not 1 followed by zeros. This is a special value that might be used to denote a variable that doesn’t yet hold a value.

In java,you can using NaN with **Double.NaN**

For example you can get NaN in these case

```
double result1 = 0.0 / 0.0;
double result2 = Math.sqrt(-1.0); 
double result3 = Math.log10(-1);
```